# What does "yet" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Yet* always makes me not understand any context. It seems that it has millions of meanings.
I have this sentence in a TOEFL reading passage.

> Finally, even if the scroll didn't point to real treasure, it has **yet** to be found. This is because the sixty-four locations the scroll describes are referred to vaguely or have ancient place names whose meanings and locations are no longer known.

What does *yet* mean in that sentence?

Comment: The sentence is illogical. The second clause is a non sequitur. To make it logical, the first clause would have to be _Finally, even if the scroll {did / claimed to [CHOOSE ONE]} point to real treasure,_. The writer had a serious mental block when creating this sentence. It wasn't proofread.

Comment: @Bill Franke: If we assume the referent of **it** is **real treasure**, the first sentence is indeed illogical in and of itself. But if we assume the referent is **the scroll**, it's a credible utterance (although ***doesn't** point* seems a more likely choice of tense, and the next sentence then becomes a non sequitur anyway).

Comment: @Fumble: The 2nd S tells us that the scroll describes 64 locations that "are referred to vaguely or have ancient place names whose meanings and locations are no longer known", so "**it**" has to refer to the treasure & not the scroll.

Comment: @Bill Franke: Like I said, *in and of itself*, the 1st S can be seen as credible/logical. It's only when you try to incorporate the 2nd S that things unavoidably come unstuck.

Answer (score 1):

It just means that the treasure has not been found.

Comment: -1 What does "it" mean in your answer? You've used it twice, but the second "it" has no referent and badly needs one. The sentence in the OP's question is both ambiguous and illogical. Your answer is unclear.

Comment: Bill, I meant that treasure has not been found yet. That's the meaning that I got from the quote. Why the downvote?

Comment: Now that I've reread the question, I can see that it's not quite as ambiguous as I thought. I can change the downvote if the answer is edited. I don't know whether that means you have to edit it or someone else can edit it. All that needs to be done is for the second "it" to be changed to "the treasure" and the word "yet" to be deleted. That makes the answer complete. I apologize for being too hasty.

Comment: I can see what you mean, Bill. I did not explain myself clearly. That happens sometimes. Your edit was logical and therefore good.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest equivalent of yet (in this context) is **still.** "It has yet to be found," means it is **still** to be found."

Answer (score 0):

" it has yet to be found. "
Means "from the time people started looking, until this moment, it has not been found.  It is possible that it will be found in the future."

Used in this sense, "yet" is indicating that a state or action began in the past, has continued to the present, and has not stopped.

Answer (score -1):

It means that

> There are problems regarding finding the treasure, Still It needs to be found.

The use of still here is along the lines of **in spite of, Despite of**.

Another use of **yet** in similar context

> He has been brillant for X team his whole carrer, Yet he needs to win this game for them else his legacy will be ruined.

Comment: -1 The sentence in the OP's question is both ambiguous and illogical. Your answer doesn't explain what it means.